Recently laid off senior frontend developer doesn’t feel very senior and is looking for advice
I have fifteen years of experience in frontend (and some backend) development.
However, my skills have atrophied thanks to some bad personal life and mental health struggles over the past few years, and the fact that I didn't get any complex, interesting, or greenfield work during the two year tenure at my most recent job.
It's been years since I've me mentored anyone junior to me and I've never really done any system design even though I've built projects from the ground up before and picked the frontend stack.
Lately I've been working on refreshing my JavaScript and React skills.
Is it possible to apply to mid-level or junior roles as a senior? I assume mid-level is more doable and won't raise as many red flags.
Any advice or perspective is welcome.

Do you only want to be doing (more) coding in your next role, or would you consider something different, like (3rd line) audit?

Are you aware of imposter syndrome?

@infinitezero -- Yeah, I'm aware of imposter syndrome and I'm working on it while skilling up, taking courses, working on leetcode, etc.
Right now I'm struggling with building some react apps without looking at examples and old code but I'm trying to retain the information.

@Dimitri Vulis -- I'd certainly consider doing something different but I enjoy coding most of the time.

OK since you don't want senior-level chores - applying to mid-level coding shouldn't raise red flags. On your cv, may want to downplay your other skills and seniority level in prior positions, so people who haven't interviewed you don't assume that you want more money than they're willing to pay.

You can apply for any position you want to. But, the companies won't likely hire you for a junior position. It makes more sense to apply for mid-level or senior positions.

I just personally find it interesting that as a fellow React developer you have been going through the same thing I have been going through. Although I have more skills than just frontend developer. I have cybersecurity and DevOps skills and will be leveraging those for 2025 and beyond plus my backend skills since the frontend part of my career is dead after almost a whole year without finding employment.

@Daniel -- Man, a whole year, that's rough. Honestly I've been looking into getting into AWS and DevOps but I don't know if switching make sense.

"Seniority" in a job is not something tatooed to your forehead, nor is it some affliction that you cannot recover from.
If you don't want the additional responsibility, for whatever reason, I see no problem applying to roles that are "mid level".
After all, there is no fixed definition for a "senior" anyway, other than it's more than mid-level, which itself has no valid general definition other than "more than junior". So a company that looks for mid level or senior has very vague notion of the exact difference between the two anyway.
Just apply for mid-level jobs. As long as you are fine with a mid-level salary, I see no problem from either side.

Let the children code quickly and show how great they are.
The adults in the room know who/what/how to code and get a product out the door.
So, you are nervous? That is fine if you don't let it run away with you. Keep in mind that we are in an industry that is like trying to build on quicksand. Most of the specific skills that we are learning this year are obsolete in 3 or 4 years.
What isn't obsolete is the experience and how to think. Consider your past work. If you primarily moved in a forward direction (learned more, understood goals, testing, etc.) then you have meaningful skills.
Does this mean you can rest on your laurels? No. Can you work with people that might know the current tech a little better than you? Yes.
You will always pick up speed on the new tech. Enjoy the fact you already have the experience.
